# Avoid putting extra slash on url mod rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using this rewrite rules in an .htacces file

```
RewriteRule ^(main|login|apps|user)/?$ index.php?_app_schema=system&_app_group=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(main|login|apps|user)/([A-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?_app_schema=system&_app_group=$1&_app_option=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(main|login|apps|user)/([A-z0-9]+)/([A-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?_app_schema=system&_app_group=$1&_app_option=$2&_app_action=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

I want to avoid users to do this

mysite.com//////user/////login

mysite.com//main////

mysite.com///apps////app001

For some reason I can put all the slashes that I wanted.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that Apache is normalizing the URL before it gets to your rules.  You can access the actual request using %{THE_REQUEST} but you will want to be careful since that variable will be completely un-sanitized.  I'd suggest you either use RewriteCond rules to compare THE_REQUEST to what you would like to match, or you could use RewriteCond to check for instances of multiple slashes and kick those requests out.